# Why is my proof that a space is closed incorrect?

Tags: metric-spaces

A metric space $X$ is closed if every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converges in the space. A space is closed if it contains all its boundary points, so then I thought one could show a space is closed by showing that an arbitrary point in the space is a boundary point. This could be done by taking an arbitrary point $x \in X$, and showing that for every $\epsilon > 0 $ one can find a point $y\notin X $, such that $d(x, y) < \epsilon$.

I understood this is an invalid way to show a space is closed, since with this method I managed to show that $c_{00}$ (the space of sequences thats eventually only zeroes) is closed. But $c_{00}$ is *not* closed, so my proof method above must clearly be wrong.

**Where is my proof method wrong?**

Comment: Well you'd have to show us the proof in order to see what's wrong. As a simpler counterexample consider $x=1$ and $X=[0,2]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The fact that every point is a boundary point does not imply that a set is closed. Consider the unit circle (in the plane) with a single point removed. All the remaining points are boundary points. So is the removed point. Therefore the set does not contain all its boundary points. Hence it is not closed.

Comment: Also, note that you should be proving that $X$ contains all it's boundary points, not that all the points of $X$ are boundary points. Try to see the difference between these two.

Comment: That is exactly what the OP said in the last phrase of the first paragraph. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Every metric space is closed (in itself) . What do you mean by saying that $c_{00}$ is not closed. Are you talking about completeness of metric spaces? F or me the entire question  makes little sense.